# Calculating an inserted image's resizing factor

Tags: graphics

When inserting an image into a LaTeX document, it might be resized for different reasons.

I need to calculate how much the original image has been resized upon insertion into the document - any ideas for this?

```
\begin{figure}
\centerline{
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image1}
}
\caption{Image 1 (resized by a factor of **???**}
\label{fig:image1}
\centering
\end{figure}
```

*EDITED after Christian Hupfer's answer*
Thanks for your suggestion, it worked perfectly.
Here is my working code and screenshots of the compiled PDF:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xfp}

\begin{document}

\newlength\scaledwidth
\begin{figure}
\centering
\newbox\mybox
\setbox\mybox=\hbox{\includegraphics[scale=1]{test}}

\setlength\scaledwidth{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\scaledwidth]{test}

\caption{Image 1 (resized to \fpeval{round((\scaledwidth/\wd\mybox)*100,2)}\% of the original image size)}
\label{fig:image1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\newbox\mybox
\setbox\mybox=\hbox{\includegraphics[scale=1]{test-small}}

\setlength\scaledwidth{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\scaledwidth]{test-small}

\caption{Image 2 (resized to \fpeval{round((\scaledwidth/\wd\mybox)*100,2)}\% of the original image size)}
\label{fig:image2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: First page of the compiled PDF document - image is larger than the text width]
[image: Second page of the compiled PDF document - image is larger than the text width]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: off-topic: don't use `\centerline{...}`. Better is `\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image1}
\caption{Image 1 (resized by a factor of **???**}
\label{fig:image1}
\end{figure}`. Why you like to resize image? You already do this with `width=\textwidth` -- size of image is resized to text width.

Comment: @Zarko - The image will automatically be resized upon insertion, except in the very unlikely case that the image width fits the text width exactly, while not exceeding the page height. See my edit for the wanted output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible solution to get the scaling factor: Store the image  in a box named, say, `\mybox` and get its width with `\wd\mybox`. Define another length for the scaling width and get the scaling factor with `\fpeval` from the result of `\scaledwidth/\wd\mybox`, the rounding is limited to 2 decimals, i.e. `round(\scaledwidth/\wd\mybox,2)` inside of `\fpeval`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xfp}
\begin{document}

\newlength\scaledwidth
\begin{figure}
\centering
\newbox\mybox
\setbox\mybox=\hbox{\includegraphics[scale=1]{ente}}

\setlength\scaledwidth{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\scaledwidth]{ente}

\caption{Image 1 (resized by a factor of \fpeval{round(\scaledwidth/\wd\mybox,2)}}
\label{fig:image1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I must confess, that I not see any reason to do this. The sam is obtained by `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ente}` ... and then  `\fpeval{\textwidth/(\wd\mybox)}` or I miss something?

Comment: @Zarko: Think of the case where the image is not scaled to the `\textwidth`

Comment: Thanks @ChristianHupfer, it worked perfectly - see my edited question for my final results