# Setting variables and assigning to figure scale in tex

Tags: macros, graphics

I am trying to assign a variable with a floating point scale value and set this equal to the scale for a number of figures. Collecting some information online I came up with the following syntax:

```
Figures .... depict the variations for the one-dimensional problem.
\newcommand{\SketchScale)}{0.5}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\subfloat{
\includegraphics[scale = {\SketchScale},trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{SchematicConstantLoadRigidBC}}
\subfloat{
\includegraphics[scale = {\SketchScale},trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{SchematicConstantLoadViscousBC}}
\subfloat{
\includegraphics[scale = {\SketchScale},trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{SchematicPeriodicLoadRigidBC}}
\subfloat{
\includegraphics[scale = {\SketchScale},trim={0 0 0 0},clip]{SchematicPeriodicLoadRigidBC}}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Running this however causes a number of errors on the lines where the variable occurs. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Would anyone please provide some assistance? Thank you.

Comment: duplicae to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372502/calculating-an-inserted-images-resizing-factor/372503?noredirect=1#comment920518_372503?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\newcommand{\SketchScale)}{0.5}
```

will generate syntax error because of the `)`  it should be

```
\newcommand{\SketchScale}{0.5}
```

and

```
scale = {\SketchScale},trim={0 0 0 0},clip
```

The  `{}` are spurious here, it should be

```
scale = \SketchScale,trim=0 0 0 0,clip
```

or more simply

```
scale = \SketchScale
```

since the trim and clip keys are doing nothing useful in this context.

Comment: True but I would like to rectify: `{SketchScale}` does not generate any errors. Indeed the extra parentheses does, however.

Comment: @user32882 actually you got lucky there and the braces are being dropped, they shouldn't be there though. (I'll edit answer to correct)